# Ionic fails building in macos 12 (Monterey)

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run "ionic cordova build ios" on my newly updated macos 12 (Monterey) I'm receiving this error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
at macosRelease (/Applications/XXX.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/macos-release/index.js:26:26)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/XXX.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/main/utils/errors.js:54:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:32)
at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:728:14)
at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:853:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
```

Answer (score 41):

edit nameMap like this

```
const nameMap = new Map([
    [21, ['Monterey', '12']],
    [20, ['Big Sur', '11']],
    [19, ['Catalina', '10.15']],
    [18, ['Mojave', '10.14']],
    [17, ['High Sierra', '10.13']],
    [16, ['Sierra', '10.12']],
    [15, ['El Capitan', '10.11']],
    [14, ['Yosemite', '10.10']],
    [13, ['Mavericks', '10.9']],
    [12, ['Mountain Lion', '10.8']],
    [11, ['Lion', '10.7']],
    [10, ['Snow Leopard', '10.6']],
    [9, ['Leopard', '10.5']],
    [8, ['Tiger', '10.4']],
    [7, ['Panther', '10.3']],
    [6, ['Jaguar', '10.2']],
    [5, ['Puma', '10.1']]
]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To find the file to edit, look at the top of the error call stack. `/Applications/XXX.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/macos-release/index.js` in this case.

Comment: Hacky... but I like it!

Comment: [22, ['Ventura', '13']],   adding ventura worked for me :) thanks

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me:

```sh
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@10.0.0
```

Comment: not working for me, the nameMap hack helped though

Comment: this one worked for me

Answer (score 16):

To fix it, simply install the latest [macos-release](https://www.npmjs.com/package/macos-release), using `npm install macos-release@3.0.1 --save` and MacOS 12 (Monterey) will be defined.

Comment: it's working for me, thanks @frankyt79

Comment: This worked for me finally.

Comment: This did it. But before this worked I had to change permissions (even though I'm an admin). This short article solves that... https://www.dailytask.co/task/error-eacces-permission-denied-rename-usrlocallibnodemodulescdk8s-clinodemodulescliui-ahmed-zidan

Answer (score 11):

After digging the source code of the "macos-release" library I found that the 'Monterey' version was not present in this array and that was the cause of the problem:

```
const nameMap = new Map([
    [20, ['Big Sur', '11']],
    [19, ['Catalina', '10.15']],
    [18, ['Mojave', '10.14']],
    [17, ['High Sierra', '10.13']],
    [16, ['Sierra', '10.12']],
    [15, ['El Capitan', '10.11']],
    [14, ['Yosemite', '10.10']],
    [13, ['Mavericks', '10.9']],
    [12, ['Mountain Lion', '10.8']],
    [11, ['Lion', '10.7']],
    [10, ['Snow Leopard', '10.6']],
    [9, ['Leopard', '10.5']],
    [8, ['Tiger', '10.4']],
    [7, ['Panther', '10.3']],
    [6, ['Jaguar', '10.2']],
    [5, ['Puma', '10.1']]
]);
```

This "macos-release" library was a dependency of "cordova": "^9.0.0", so the solution that worked for me was to remove this library from my package.json file, delete "node-modules" folder an install all the dependencies again.

Another solution would be upgrading to cordova 10.0.0.

Answer (score 11):

For the ones who updated to Ventura you should add this also:

```
[22, ['Ventura', '13']],
```

So it will be like;

```
const nameMap = new Map([
    [22, ['Ventura', '13']],
    [21, ['Monterey', '12']],
    [20, ['Big Sur', '11']],
    [19, ['Catalina', '10.15']],
    [18, ['Mojave', '10.14']],
    [17, ['High Sierra', '10.13']],
    [16, ['Sierra', '10.12']],
    [15, ['El Capitan', '10.11']],
    [14, ['Yosemite', '10.10']],
    [13, ['Mavericks', '10.9']],
    [12, ['Mountain Lion', '10.8']],
    [11, ['Lion', '10.7']],
    [10, ['Snow Leopard', '10.6']],
    [9, ['Leopard', '10.5']],
    [8, ['Tiger', '10.4']],
    [7, ['Panther', '10.3']],
    [6, ['Jaguar', '10.2']],
    [5, ['Puma', '10.1']]
]);
```

If you don't know your version try `console.log(release);` in function `const macosRelease = release => {...`

Answer (score 6):

Started facing the issue when i updated my macOs to Ventura (13). Therefore just simply added the Os name version in the HashMap, without updating anything.

```
const nameMap = new Map([
    [21, ['Ventura', '13']],
    [20, ['Big Sur', '11']],
    [19, ['Catalina', '10.15']],
    [18, ['Mojave', '10.14']],
    [17, ['High Sierra', '10.13']],
    [16, ['Sierra', '10.12']],
    [15, ['El Capitan', '10.11']],
    [14, ['Yosemite', '10.10']],
    [13, ['Mavericks', '10.9']],
    [12, ['Mountain Lion', '10.8']],
    [11, ['Lion', '10.7']],
    [10, ['Snow Leopard', '10.6']],
    [9, ['Leopard', '10.5']],
    [8, ['Tiger', '10.4']],
    [7, ['Panther', '10.3']],
    [6, ['Jaguar', '10.2']],
    [5, ['Puma', '10.1']]
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I got the same error, but the problem was that I did not have Cordova installed at all (I was working on an old Ionic 3 project on a new machine and did not even think about not having Cordova installed)

So first check if corodva istalled

```
npm list -g cordova
npm list cordova
```

If not, install it:

```
npm install cordova
```

Answer (score 1):

If appending the macOs version to `app-release` doesn't fix your issue, you might consider to uninstall the cordova globally and re-install.

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova
```

Use `sudo` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Go into node_modules/macos-release/index.js

and append `[21, ['Monterey', '12']],` into the nameMap.

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing just one file wasn't enough. After changing `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/macos-release/index.js` I got errors in other dependencies (e.g. `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/os-name/node_modules/macos-release/index.js`.

So I went to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/` and performed ad `npm install insight@0.11.1`.

This fixed everything in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened a new Terminal tab and "ionic info" started working.