# Ionic Info :TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: angular, xcode, ionic-framework

I am working on Ionic Capacitor Project.

I have recently updated my Mac OS to 12.0.1 and XCode to 13.1.

I am getting various issues, but when I try to preform a Ionic Info I am getting following error messages:

```
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

at macosRelease (/Users/dharmeshjoshi/Documents/App Project/node_modules/macos-release/index.js:26:26)
at osName (/Users/dharmeshjoshi/Documents/App Project/node_modules/os-name/index.js:21:18)
at Environment.getInfo (/Users/dharmeshjoshi/Documents/App Project/node_modules/ionic/lib/index.js:45:20)
at async InfoCommand.run (/Users/dharmeshjoshi/Documents/App Project/node_modules/ionic/commands/info.js:29:24)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async InfoCommand.execute (/Users/dharmeshjoshi/Documents/App Project/node_modules/ionic/lib/command.js:79:9)
at async Executor.run (/Users/dharmeshjoshi/Documents/App Project/node_modules/ionic/lib/executor.js:53:9)
at async Executor.execute (/Users/dharmeshjoshi/Documents/App
Project/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/lib/executor.js:69:13)
at async Object.run (/Users/dharmeshjoshi/Documents/App Project/node_modules/ionic/index.js:104:9)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Check this! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68318289/ionic-fails-building-in-macos-12-monterey