# const [name, version] = nameMap.get(release);

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

const [name, version] = nameMap.get(release);
^

TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
at macosRelease (/Users/saileshkumar/MyProjects/SyncDriver/SyncDriver/node_modules/os-name/node_modules/macos-release/index.js:27:26)
at osName (/Users/saileshkumar/MyProjects/SyncDriver/SyncDriver/node_modules/os-name/index.js:21:18)
at new Insight (/Users/saileshkumar/MyProjects/SyncDriver/SyncDriver/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:37:13)
at new RelentlessInsight (/Users/saileshkumar/MyProjects/SyncDriver/SyncDriver/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:31:1)
at Object. (/Users/saileshkumar/MyProjects/SyncDriver/SyncDriver/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:39:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)

Solution to resolve above issue in while building in MAC OS Version 13

Comment: look this answer.
add https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68318289/ionic-fails-building-in-macos-12-monterey/69311625#69311625

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you are using a version for your mac that has not yet been added to the node_module your using. Can you go to the file and check that the version you are using has been added? The file should look like this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/macos-release/blob/main/index.js

If not, I think you should be able to update the plugin and that should fix the issue.

Otherwise some more information would be useful. Did everything work well with macOS12 and break when you updated your mac? that is my assumption now.

see also : [Ionic fails building in macos 12 (Monterey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68318289/ionic-fails-building-in-macos-12-monterey)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you used node 14 and latest cordova, the issue will disappears

Answer (score 0):

If you are running **sudo ionic cordova build android** on your mac after updating your Mac OS to **Ventura** from previous version. Then kindly follow these steps to build your app.

1. Open index.js path would be /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/macos-release.
2. Replace line const [name, version] = nameMap.get(release);
   by **const [name,version]=('Macos','1.0.0');**
   thats all, it will work.
   **if you follow above steps you dont have to upgrade your cordova and any other enviornment.**